# x86 Assembly (NASM) How to nth root or raise floating point value with fraction

Tags: assembly, root, nasm, exponent

I have an upcoming project next week and I have been spending the last 2 days figuring out how to do an nth root.

I need to Simulate Geometric Mean in Assembly NASM.

I know FPU has an instruction for Square Rooting but that won't really take me far.

Currently, I can input as many inputs as I want and it multiplies them with no problem. But I get stuck with the 'nth root' part as I do not know how to do it with NASM.

This is my current code:

```
    global _main
    extern _printf, _scanf, _system

    section .text

    _main:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
push clr
call _system
add esp, 4

    ; start of INITIALIZE
    ;printf("Enter number of elements")
push print1
call _printf
add esp, 4
    ; scanf number of elements
push n
push scan1
call _scanf
add esp, 8

   ; printf("enter n integers")
   push dword [n]
push print2
call _printf
add esp, 8

   fld qword [n2]


   ; scan first element
   push n2
   push scan2
   call _scanf
   add esp, 8

   fld qword [n2]

   JE J1

   MOV EBX, 1

   CMP EBX, [n]
   JE J1

   L1:

   push n2
   push scan2
   call _scanf 
   add esp, 8

   fld qword [n2]
   fmul st1, st0
   fstp qword [ans]

   INC EBX
   CMP EBX, dword [n]
   JE J1
   LOOP L1

   J1:

   fst qword [ans]

   push dword [ans+4]
   push dword [ans]
   push print3
   call _printf
  add  esp, 12

   mov dword [data8], n

   fld qword [data7]
   fld qword [data8]

   fdiv st1, st0

   fstp qword [ans]


   fst qword [ans]

   push dword [ans+4]
   push dword [ans]
   push print3
   call _printf
  add  esp, 12

   xor eax, eax
   ret

   section .data
   clr      db "cls", 0
   print1   db "Enter the number of elements:", 13,10,0
   scan1    db "%d" , 0
   scan2    db "%lf" , 0
   n        dd 0
   n2       dq 0.0
   n3       dq 0.0
   print2   db "Enter %d values:", 13,10,0
   print3   db "Value is %g", 13, 10,0
   data8    dq 3.0
   ans      dq 0.0
   loopstart dq 1.0
   data7    dq 1.0
```

Or is it also possible to use an external C function for extracting an nth root?

EDIT: Trying to use the _pow from C. I have this code but it isn't working can someone help?

```
       LEA ESI, [return]

       push ESI
       push dword [pushingthing+4]
       push dword [pushingthing]
       push dword [ans+4]
       push dword [ans]
       push pow1
       call _pow
       add  esp, 24

       section   .data

       return   dq 0.0
       pushingthing dq 2.0
       pow1     dd "%g, %g", 13, 10, 0
```

Doing this because pow (in C) has a format of pow(x,y) which are both double and returns a double value. Please check.

Comment: Sure, you can use the C `pow` function knowing that `n`-th root is same as power to the `1/n`. In assembly, you can use logarithms.

Comment: I still don't quite know how to push floating point values to a C function that has a return value. Is it possible for you to teach me? I've been searching around the internet for a solution but I'm stumped.

Comment: That is described in the calling convention for your platform (that you didn't mention). Generally you pass input arguments on the cpu stack, and get back the result in `st(0)`.

Comment: I think the calling convention is ISAx87. I still do not quite get it so I will try another solution. You mentioned logarithms in Assembly, but the current instruction set that I have is automatically set to log2. I am no math genius so I really have no idea how to tackle this.

Comment: `n-th root = 2^(log2(x) / n)`

Comment: Updated main post to clarify help in using pow function. Please help. With the current formula, I still would have to use pow as there's no direct way raise 2 by the log2 formula in assembly.

Answer (score 4):

Using `push` to pass arguments, especially doubles, will make your head hurt with all the reversing and halving :)  You should just allocate space and use the appropriate mov instructions. You still didn't say what environment you are in, but most of them return result in `st(0)` (ie. floating point stack). As such, an example could be:

```
sub esp, 16          ; space for 2 doubles
fld qword [x]        ; load 1st arg
fstp qword [esp]     ; write to stack
fld qword [y]        ; load 2nd arg
fstp qword [esp+8]   ; write to stack
call _pow
; result is now in st(0) print it
mov dword [esp], fmt ; format string
fstp qword [esp+4]   ; pass result as arg
call _printf
add esp, 16          ; free stack space

x: dq 16.0
y: dq 0.25
fmt: db "%g", 13, 10, 0
```

Comment: Holy moly it works. Thank you and you're definitely saving my hide right now.